# Android icon is missing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why after 'run' the Android application project, the smartphone home screen does not display the application logo? while the installation was successful and running.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name=".FirebaseDBReadActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FirebaseDBActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FirebaseDBCreateActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FirebaseDBReadSingleActivity"/>
</application>
```

-----------ic_luncher.xml---------

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

Comment: Hello @Riki Please make sure that you logo availble in mipmp-xxxhdpi

Comment: already, 'android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

Comment: is your ic_launcher.xml in mipmap folder please check that

Comment: yes, complete, hdpi, mdpi, xxxhdpi, etc.

Comment: in which version of your device you are facing issue?

Comment: Run the 'application' from Android Studio, there are no problems, the application is installed, normal, but there is no icon on the smartphone home screen.

Comment: I think Adaptive icon requied API 26 so you need to update your buildtools to at least 26.0.0 version so can you check that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208822/discussion-between-parth-lotia-and-riki).

Comment: Can you find the icon and the application listed in the settings > applications ?

Comment: oh, it turns out my smartphone needs to be cleared of cache

Answer (score 0):

Can you check **android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"** file?
If this not your app icon change with your icon.

Comment: oh, it turns out my smartphone needs to be cleared of cache